# error when using head command inside while loop

Tags: linux, bash, awk, head

Friends,

I am trying to write a script which would take two fields(separated by '.') from a file and interchange them and insert them into another file. The program would do for n number of records. Below given the script

```
#!/bin/ksh
k=`wc -l file1|cut -d' ' -f1`
i=1
while [ $i -le $k ]
do
    var1=`awk 'BEGIN {FS = "."};{print $2}' file1|head -$i|tail -1`
    var2=`awk 'BEGIN {FS = "."};{print $1}' file1|head -$i|tail -1`
    c="$var1.$var2"
    echo $c >> results.txt
    i=$i+1
done
```

I am getting the below error in head command. Could you help me here.

head: unrecognized option `-+'
Try`head --help' for more information.

Comment: You should try not to use back tics if you can use the new parentheses. Like this:  `var1=$(awk '.....' file)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the line `i=$i+1` transforms `i` into `1+1`, then into `1+1+1` and so on.

Why not just use:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="."};{print $2"."$1}' <file1 >results.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

What you've written can be handled by just a single `awk` command like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="."} {print $2, $1 > "resultst.txt"}' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your shell doesn't know quite what you mean by:

```
i=$i+1
```

and so `i` is getting the value `+` or similar. Try using `expr` on it (check your man page)

As an aside - your approach is completely wrong, this whole thing should be a concise, trivial awk script.

Comment: you are correct sir. i changed that into i = `expr $i + 1` and the script worked fine. And your second point is correct. I know only basics of awk so couldnt realise the whole thing can be acheived in one command.

Answer (score 0):

This sed will do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\2.\1/' file1 > results.txt
```

It matches the two subexpression separated by a dot and then exchange the references. Notice that in the left you must escape the dot or it will be interpreted as part of a regular expression while that is not needed in the right side.